# Very basic Keras CNN with 2 classes giving inexplicable answers

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras

Tried training a very simple CNN with Keras/Theano on a binary classification problem.  The loss function always converges to 8.0151 or so.  Parameter/architecture modifications did not help.  So I made a very simple example: new input arrays, one is all ones, the other all zeroes.  No dice, same behavior.  I tried all 1's and all -1's, same thing.  Then, all 0's and random.  Same.  Lowered dimensions and depth, removed dropout, monkeyed with parameters, same.  Help!  What is happening?

```
import numpy

A = []
B = []

for j in range(100):
    npa = numpy.array([[1 for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)])
    A.append(npa.reshape(1,npa.shape[0],npa.shape[1]))

for j in range(100):
    npa = numpy.array([[0 for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)])
    B.append(npa.reshape(1,npa.shape[0],npa.shape[1]))

trainXA = []
trainXB = []
testXA = []
testXB = []

for j in range(len(A)):
    if ((j+2) % 7) != 0:
        trainXA.append(A[j])
        trainXB.append(B[j])
    else:
        testXA.append(A[j])
        testXB.append(B[j])

X_train = numpy.array(trainXA + trainXB)
X_test = numpy.array(testXA + testXB)

Y_train = numpy.array([[1,0] for i in range(len(X_train)/2)] + [[0,1] for i in range(len(X_train)/2)])

import random

def jumblelists(C,D):
    outC = []
    outD = []
    for j in range(len(C)):
        newpos = int(random.random()*(len(outC)+1))
        outC = outC[:newpos]+[C[j]]+outC[newpos:]
        outD = outD[:newpos]+[D[j]]+outD[newpos:]
    return numpy.array(outC),numpy.array(outD)

X_train,Y_train = jumblelists(X_train,Y_train)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1,100,100)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your learning rate is simply set way too high, probably leading to an explosion in weights and gradient. Simply change

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

to

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

You might also want to try a different optimizer. Adam with default settings is often a good choice.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to help a lot (lowering the learning rate).  The toy examples I mentioned above trained correctly right away.  Trying out real problems now.  Strange that the Keras main documentation "VGG-like convnet" example has a learning rate of 0.1...

Comment: @anonymous_coward Different networks require different learning rates, best is to use an adaptive learning rate (like with the ADAM optimizer).

Comment: @anonymous_coward if this post answered your question, please mark this answer as accepted (click the check mark below of the up/downvote buttons). Thanks!